# jquery-datatables-rails TableTools or Buttons?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

In a Rails4 app, I'm using gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'.
I want to use dataTable's built in ability to save as xls or pdf.

I'm getting the error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf
```

This works:

```
sSwfPath: "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
```

But, the gem has the swf file in it.

Here's a pic of the gem contents:

[image]

I tried the following:

```
sSwfPath: "/media/dataTables/extras/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
sSwfPath: "../media/dataTables/extras/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
sSwfPath: "/jquery3.3.0/app/assets/media/dataTables/extras/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
```

Comment: The full path should be "localhost:3000/assets/dataTables/extras/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"; Try with sSwfPath: "/dataTables/extras/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"

Comment: `http://localhost:5000/dataTables/extras/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf` not found

Comment: `sSwfPath: "assets/dataTables/extras/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"` worked. Thanks - create answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: do you need to add/copy the 'copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf' into the asset pipeline? because in my Projekt I could not point to that file. Currently it is working with the cdn call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full path should be "localhost:3000/assets/dataTables/extras/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf";

Try with

```
sSwfPath: "assets/dataTables/extras/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
```